# When date and timedatectl?

Tags: date, time, timezone

About reporting and settings for *date* and *time* exists available the `date` and `timedatectl` commands - it according with the most common results available through the web. Practically both do the same.

So when for an explicit scenario(s) one would be mandatory over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is a part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation), it is available on all Linux systems, it is frequently used in scripting.

`timedatectl` is a part of [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html).

The two tools are used to set/display time and date.

see : `info date`,   `man timedatectl`

Answer (score 4):

There is one important difference:

When you set a time with the `date` command then only system time is changed.
But if you set a time with the `timedatectl` then both system time and default rtc time is affected.

If you want update rtc time after the `date` change then you need to use `hwclock`.

Answer (score 2):

`date` is an old UNIX tool, `timedatectl` is a new tool by systemd creators, so it's only available in distros with `systemd`.

Use whatever you like whenever it's available.